# How to fetch data from json file using angular HttpClient service using pipe and filter?

Tags: json, angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

[image]

**Above is the structure of json data.**

[image]

**Above is the code I wrote to fetch "AllTranscations" array for particular user.**

Can someone please help me with what logic I'm putting wrong in getAllTansactionsByUser().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this:

```
return this.http.get<Transaction[]>(this.userDataURL).pipe(
  map(data => data
    .filter(transaction => transaction.UID === UID)
    .map(transaction => transaction.AllTransactions)
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It solved my problem.